# How to stop x-axis values from overlapping

Tags: python

```
teams = ['Ari', 'Atl', 'Bal', 'Buf', 'Caro', 'Chi', 'Cinci', 'Clev', 'Dal', 'Den', 'Det', 'GB', 'Hous', 'Indi', 'Jack', 'KC', 'LA(R)', 'LA(C)', 'Mia', 'Minn', 'NE', 'NO', 'NY(G)', 'NY(J)', 'Oak', 'Phila', 'Pitt', 'SF', 'Seat', 'TB', 'Tenn', 'Wash']
totalWon = np.array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 6, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 6, 5, 1, 1, 0, 3])
totalLost = np.array([1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2])
ind = [x for x, _ in enumerate(teams)]

plt.bar(ind, totalWon, width=0.8, label='Wins', color='blue', bottom=totalLost)
plt.bar(ind, totalLost, width=0.8, label='Losses', color='red')


plt.xticks(ind, teams)
plt.ylabel("Total Games")
plt.xlabel("NFL Teams")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.title("Super Bowls Wins/Losses Per Team")

plt.show()
```

This is my first time working with plotting data on Python. I got to outputted plot that I wanted but the values on the x-axis are really jumbled up and they overlap, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Parameter rotation can be added to `plt.xticks`. I got this image by changing `plt.xticks` from your code.

```
plt.xticks(ind, teams, rotation=60)
```

[image]